# Azure Blob Service, in Mobile Services, stops working when not running App from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services to develop an app which will upload and download blobs across different devices.

I was using the SAS model, which I removed because security was not at all a concern for me, and was only interested in doing things the 'rough way' (I'm sure I'll get a lot of criticism for this, but hope you can still appreciate the rest of my problem).

So basically I am setting up a `CloudBlobClient` using the Account name and key directly. Then I setup the containers (in the case when uploading the blobs I do `CreateIfNotExists`) and ultimately I run `UploadFromStreamAsync` or `DownloadToStreamAsync` accordingly.

Now, everything works fine and dandy until I unplug the USB cable from the PC. If I run it from Visual Studio (both Release and Debug versions) it runs fine. If I unplug the cable and try to run it, it doesn't. Also does not work if I deploy it first using XapDeply (both Debug and Release Xap).

After a lot of debugging (since it all works fine on the debugger I had to print everything to a log file), I realize that the `InsertAsync` and other such operations on Azure (using the tables) are working fine. But those three methods mentioned:

`CreateIfNotExists`, `UploadFromStreamAsync` and `DownloadToStreamAsync`

These do not work and result in:

```
Exception.Type : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Exception.InnerException : 
Exception.Exception Message : The argument 'ParallelOperationThreadCount' is larger than maximum of '64'
Parameter name: ParallelOperationThreadCount
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertInBounds[T](String paramName, T val, T min, T max)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions.set_ParallelOperationThreadCount(Nullable`1 value)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions.ApplyDefaults(BlobRequestOptions options, BlobType blobType, CloudBlobClient serviceClient, Boolean applyExpiry)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.BeginCreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.BeginCreateIfNotExists(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.TaskFromApm[TResult](Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endMethod, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()
   at AzureLink.AzureServices.BlobUpload.<SetContainer>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I've been baffled by this for the last hours, and am very very clueless, the only thing that occurred to me was that perhaps it ABSOLUTELY needs the SAS authentication. This implies quite a bit of changes to the way I'm doing things, and perhaps it's the only solution. But I am still very curious as to why it would work while connected to Visual Studio and immediately stop once it's not running from Visual Studio.

I'm sure I am missing something and would really like to understand this, thank you for your patience, and let me know if you want more log files or code or something. I didn't paste all the code, because it seems the problem is more on the difference between being connected to VS or not, and why those Azure functions would work great in one case and not the other.

**EDIT**: Adding my BlobUpload Class (sorry for the length, it's a bit too encapsulated but I was trying to isolate the problem) Also sorry for the delay, working in a low connectivity area:

```
class BlobUpload
{
    private String ResourceName;
    private String ContainerName;

    private const string endpoint = "https://[svname].blob.core.windows.net";
    private const string accountKey = "key==";
    private const string accountName = "[svname]";

    public FarmerBlobUpload(String resourceName, String containerName)
    {
        ResourceName = resourceName;
        ContainerName = containerName;
    }

    private CloudBlobClient blobClient = null;
    private CloudBlobContainer container = null;
    private CloudBlockBlob blob = null;

    private bool SetClient()
    {
        try
        {
            blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(
                new Uri(string.Format(endpoint)),
                new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetClient - Exception : " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> SetContainer()
    {
        if (blobClient == null)
            if (!SetClient())
                return false;

        try
        {
            container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName.ToLower());
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: CreateIfNotExistsAsync");
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetPermissionsAsync");
            await container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container
            });
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetContainer - Exception TYPE : " + e.GetType());
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetContainer - Exception InnerException : " + e.InnerException);
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetContainer - Exception Message : " + e.Message);
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetContainer - Exception StackTrace : " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> SetBlockBlob()
    {
        if (container == null)
            if (!(await SetContainer()))
                return false;

        try
        {
            blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(ResourceName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: SetBlockBlob - Exception : " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> UploadFile(IsolatedStorageFile isoStore)
    {
        if (blob == null)
            if (!(await SetBlockBlob()))
                return false;

        try
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isoStore.OpenFile(ResourceName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            bool xx = await blob.ExistsAsync();
            if (!xx)
            {
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(isfs);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: UploadFile - Exception TYPE : " + e.GetType());
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: UploadFile - Exception InnerException : " + e.InnerException);
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: UploadFile - Exception Message : " + e.Message);
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: UploadFile - Exception StackTrace : " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> UploadBlob()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isoStore.FileExists(ResourceName))
                {
                    bool res = await UploadFile(isoStore);
                    return res;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PersonalLogger.WriteLine("Upload: UploadBlob - Failure : " + ResourceName + " - " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

PersonalLogger just writes to a file, so I can read it later (since this problem only occurs when I am disconnected from the debugger).

The places where it consistently crashses is CreateIfNotExists and UploadFromStreamAsync.

The downloading class is very similar and but the crash occurs at DownloadToStreamAsync.

Basically, as soon as I unplug it from the Debugger (the USB cable) all operations which seem to access the Blob Storage in Azure crash. Table operations work fine.

Comment: Please include the actual exception type and exception message, not just the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you seeing: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The argument is out of range. Value passed: System.IO.MemoryStream
Parameter name: pageData`? If so, check: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/262

Comment: Thanks for the edit, took some time to simulate it again. Since in the debugger all works fine, I had to log the type of exception and so on, then run it all again, then get the logfile. It seems like it is `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Though I cannot see the rest of the message.

Comment: The difference here is also that as soon as I run it from VS2012 it all uploads and downloads without any problem. And then again doesn't as soon as I unplug that USB cable. Which seems to be a different problem than the one on the link... In any case thank you loads for checking it out.

Comment: In Visual Studio you're probably running against the development storage simulator and not against the actual Azure storage...

Comment: Hmm... not sure I understand what you mean. If you mean a locally installed simulator, then that's not the case, since I can check by logging in my mobile services and storage services on the Azure website that things are there.

Comment: Can you show some of the surrounding code? I have seen issues like this before when using page blobs.